# Chrome javascript geolocation not showing Allow/Block popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation

It seems since the last release of Chrome, we don't get a popup to Allow/Block accessing a user's location from a website. Tried on Edge, FF and mobile devices and it seems to work.

Current Chrome version: Version 68.0.3440.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Test URL: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error

Anyone come across this and knows how to fix it? Most of our traffic comes from Chrome!

Comment: This question is nothing about code try unblocking from chrome settings.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Check you've not already allowed or blocked for that site.

Comment: The settings are set to Ask (default) for location on w3schools. This is the same another 3 of my colleagues. @UllasHunka probably not code related unless Chrome updated something in their API settings.

Comment: There may be some firewall protection at your location contact your server administrator.

Comment: It works on all other major browsers.

Comment: The popup works on my Chrome version 67.0.3396.99. Did you see the icons right side of the omnibar? [This](https://i.imgur.com/P3EyWwi.png) is a screenshot of my Chrome, and it has that icon for "I blocked geolocation" just before the "star page" icon.

Comment: Maybe you already blocked geolocation permission for W3schools. If you see that icon, click it and you'll get a "Clear setting for future visits" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually a Chrome bug where the popup doesn't come up in full screen mode. If you run Chrome without it being fully maximized then you'll see the popup. Thanks everyone for your help!